# Setting CloudWatch Alarm for multiple instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm configuring an alarm for an instance from the Amazon CLI. for example, to trigger a notification when the cpu is idle for 5min. but I want to set this alarm for a lot of Instances.

With this Bash Script I created one alarm for one instance :

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name cpu-mon --alarm-description "Alarm when CPU exceeds 70 percent" --metric-name CPUUtilization --namespace AWS/EC2 --statistic Average --period 300 --threshold 70 --comparison-operator GreaterThanThreshold  --dimensions "Name=InstanceId,Value=i-12345678" --evaluation-periods 2 --alarm-actions arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111122223333:MyTopic --unit Percent
```

So, I don't see how can I use this script to choose another instances, or eventually loop on that script, in order to choose another instances.

Comment: Are you wanting a separate measure for each instance, or a calculated metric like an "average across multiple instances"?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a list of instance IDs you want to create alarms for you could do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
instances=(instanceId1 instanceId2 etc)
for i in "${instances[@]}"; do
    aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm \
        --alarm-name cpu-mon-${i} \
        --alarm-description "Alarm when CPU exceeds 70 percent" \
        --metric-name CPUUtilization \
        --namespace AWS/EC2 \
        --statistic Average \
        --period 300 \
        --threshold 70 \
        --comparison-operator GreaterThanThreshold  \
        --dimensions "Name=InstanceId,Value=${i}" \
        --evaluation-periods 2 \
        --alarm-actions arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111122223333:MyTopic \
        --unit Percent
done
```

You could also initially use the AWS CLI to grab instance IDs based on tags, instance names etc and then use those to create the alarms along the same lines.